# "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Articles#show " jumpstart tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on Blogger tutorial from jumpstartlab.com. I have strange problem with it. When I run server it looks quite good. I see a list of articles under "/articles". But when I try to see one of them I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Articles#show

Showing /home/rails_projects/blogger/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line
#6 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: comments.article_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
"comments"  WHERE "comments"."article_id" = ?

Extracted source (around line #6):

3
4  <%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
5
6  <h3>Comments(<%= @article.comments.count %>)</h3>
7
8  <%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
9  <%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
```

Show.html.erb :

```
<%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>

<h3>Comments(<%= @article.comments.count %>)</h3>

<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path%>
<%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article),method: :delete, :confirm => "Really   
delete the article?"
```

Articles_controller.rb

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show 
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])    

  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    @article.save

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.update_attributes(params[:article])

    flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"

    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def change
     create_table :articles do |t|
       t.string :title
       t.text :body
       t.timestamps
     end
  end

   def new
    @article = Article.new
   end

end
```

20130716025552_create_articles.rb

```
Class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.integer :article_id
      t.string  :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
   end
  end
end
```

20130717021354_create_comments.rb

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :author_name
      t.integer :article_id
      t.text :body
      t.string :article
      t.string :references

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'am very confused and really got no idea what to do with this problem.

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: seems missing migration , article_id is not present.

Comment: Do you have the article_id column in the comments table or anything else for the same?

Comment: Yes, I will paste my migration file.

Answer (score 1):

First, run `bundle exec rake db:rollback` which will rollback your last migration (and it's good, since 'create comments' migration is the last one). Then, edit your migration file:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :author_name
      t.text :body
      t.references :article

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` again.